# Gridview scrolling stutters

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I've been experimenting with Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 express but I can't achieve my goal.

I've been trying to create a grid of tiles that expands horizontally (much like the 'start' screen does).
The items are added at runtime and although scrolling horizontally works, it's not good enough.
When using my touchpad, it seems to clip to something, on a tablet this would feel laggy.
Scrolling with the cursor seems fine.

I'd like to know how I can give it a smooth experience by using XAML, unfortunately I'm not very good at it (yet).

XAML: (the stackpanel should be pointless but I was experimenting)

```
<Grid Background="White" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="109*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="622" Margin="97,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="1206,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This might be a hardware/drive issue rather than a windows-8 issue.  Have you tried it on a different computer?

Comment: The stuttering behavior only occurs in the application, the issue does not exist on the Windows 8 starts screen and neither does it exist in other store apps.

Comment: Can you post a little more code? A good start may be the code that loads the grid.

Comment: It's the default, visual studio generated, constructor.
`
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
`

Comment: As mydogisbox suggested, maybe it is your hardware. If it makes you feel any better, I have an app that runs the split application template (grid for groups, listview for details view), and it runs just fine on my MS Surface (ARM) device. The scrolling is smooth 99% of the time - the 1% of the time when it isn't smooth is when it is doing CPU intensive processing.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the issue you're facing though, but maybe it helps:
By default the `ItemsTemplatePanel` of a GridView is a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. If you don't have many items in your GridView, the scrolling of your GridView can indeed seem to be stuttering.

Try setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `StackPanel` in stead of `VirtualizingStackPanel` (unless you insist that your control GridView virtualizes its items).

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Width="Auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Hope this helps!